# estoy intentando hacer un Stopwatch pero por alguna razon me dice que this.start no es una funcion

Tags: javascript, poo

al introducir en la consola del navegador `const sw = new Stopwatch();` la consola tira un error para el metodo start, porque?. aqui les dejo mi código javascript. No entiendo porque dice que el metodo start no es una función ayuda por favor.

```
function Stopwatch()
{
    let startTime, endTime, running, duration = 0;

this.start() = function()
{
    if(running) 
    {
        throw new Error('Stopwatch has already started.');
    }

    running = true;
    startTime = new Date();
};

this.stop() = function()
{
    if(!running)
    {
        throw new Error('Stopwatch is not started.');
    }

    running = false;
    endTime = new Date();
    const seconds = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime())/1000;
    duration += seconds;
};

this.reset() = function() 
{
    startTime = null;
    endTime = null;
    running = false;
    duration = 0;
};

Object.defineProperty(this, 'duration', {
    get: function() { return duration; }
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como dice el error, `start, stop y reset` no son funciones, estás agregando paréntesis como si lo fueran, posteriormente señalas que es igual a una función, intenta quitando los paréntesis de la siguiente manera:

```js
function Stopwatch()
{
    let startTime, endTime, running, duration = 0;

this.start = function()
{
    if(running) 
    {
        throw new Error('Stopwatch has already started.');
    }

    running = true;
    startTime = new Date();
};

this.stop = function()
{
    if(!running)
    {
        throw new Error('Stopwatch is not started.');
    }

    running = false;
    endTime = new Date();
    const seconds = (endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime())/1000;
    duration += seconds;
};

this.reset = function() 
{
    startTime = null;
    endTime = null;
    running = false;
    duration = 0;
};

Object.defineProperty(this, 'duration', {
    get: function() { return duration; }
});
};


const sw = new Stopwatch();
//sw.start();
//sw.stop();
//sw.reset();
```

Una vez que colocas que es igual a una función entonces si podrás acceder a dichas funciones después de declarar el objeto de la siguiente manera, ejemplo: `sw.start();`, dejé los ejemplos comentados en el código.

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: no en realidad cundo pongo `sw.start();`  me sale esto `VM257:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: sw is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: y ya defini el objeto entonces no se que pasa

Comment: si removiste los paréntesis como marqué en el ejemplo?

Comment: ah perdon ahora los removi pero el problema ahora es que le doy a sw.start; luego de un tiempo sw.stop; y al final sw.duration; y me da duration = 0 eso no esta bien :(

Comment: no me corre el start porque si le aplicara start 2 veces seguidas deberia tirarme un mensaje de error lo cual tampoco pasa.

Comment: mira, en primera, duration = 0 siempre te marcará debido a que las funciones no veo que estén relacionadas correctamente, y en segundo, no te va a marcar error si inicias el start 2 veces debido a que se crea uno nuevo cada vez que lo ejecutas.

Comment: porque dices que no están relacionadas correctamente?

Comment: realiza una prueba imprimiendo los resultados de starttime, endtime, duration y seconds en el flujo, verifica el flujo y mira como va cambiando el valor de "duration".